# jQuery query string issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to initialize some jQuery to only run if a specific querystring is found. However I am having trouble matching the querystring in an IF statement. My code is below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if($(window.location.search == '?uploaded=success')){
            alert('test has worked');
        }
    });
```

At the minute this if statement is being ran whether ?uploaded=success is there or not.
Can anyone help shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

```
    if($(window.location.search == '?uploaded=success')){
```

should be

```
    if(window.location.search == '?uploaded=success'){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(window.location.search == '?uploaded=success')){...!?
```

You mean:

```
if (window.location.search == '?uploaded=success')
```

or:

```
if ($(window.location.search) == '?uploaded=success') {
```

Comment: I'm not so sure about that last one.